# How to add the functionality of a gift certificate in VirtueMart?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am creating an online shop using [VirtueMart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtueMart). Now I want to add facility of a gift card as we have in [Magento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento) and [OsCommerce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OsCommerce). So is there any plugin available in VirtueMart or do I have to customize VirtueMart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VM does not do Magento/OSC style gift certificates without an extension. It does support simple coupons, but they are pretty limited in how they work. Your best bet is to use AwoCoupon, it's free.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-coupons/11629

Comment: Thats i know but i have to do for my client.i have tried it but it does not full fill the clients need.

Comment: What exactly does your client need?

Comment: Actually he want to give the facility to customer that he/she can give some amount to his or her friend as a gift and print thats page and send this page to his/her friend. Whenever His or her friend comes to shop that much discount offered to him/her as send by her/his friend.I have tried by AWOCoupen Component.

Comment: You need the pro version. Sellable gift certificates with usage tracking is one of the main features of the pro version. http://dev.awofadeju.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for variable price component wherein user can enter the amount of gift certificate in the product. I don't think there is any module which will do in Virtuemart. I was also looking for this in January this year in Virtuemart so after exhaustive search I finally moved to Ubercart which has pretty good support of this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You need a third party plugin to do this, Virtuemart does not have this feature out of the box.  Try https://www.osignite.com/software/vm2-gift-certificate.html